# Slide in/out a <TD>

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a TD that is currently on the left side of the page. I want that TD to slide in and slide out (with animation).
.animate works with div but not with TD. Is there a good way to do that?

Comment: Are you asking this because you're using a table for your site's layout? Please say no.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't write the HTML. The HTML guy was crazy, I must say. Imagine! he used table inside table then another table and then another table and so on :(

Comment: Oh man, I don't envy you. Always rough dealing with legacy code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`td` elements are incredibly hard to animate due to the way they integrate into the table model. I would highly suggest using a `div` placed inside the `td` instead.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>Foo</div> <!-- animate this element instead -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or better yet, don't use a table.

Comment: I would suggest using relative positioning on the div -- start it at -400 or something, then bring it back up to zero.

Comment: @Blazemonger I did consider adding that, but it would depend on the type of animation the OP is doing.

Comment: I know this idea wont work when the adjacent TD of any other TR has the larger width. But for now its works. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, not really.

A table cell is supposed to be a part of the table, it doesn't work well if you try to position it somewhere else.